# Elasticsearch not accepting data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an Elasticsearch cluster [setup](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster) on kubernetes. Recently logstash was not able to push any data to the cluster because one of the node in the cluster was out of disk space.

This was the error in logstash

```
 [Ruby-0-Thread-13@[main]&gt;worker1: /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:383] elasticsearch - retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=&gt;"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=&gt;"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"})
```

The es-master had marked the node as read only because the available disk space crossed the threshold

```
[WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [es-master-65ccf55794-pm4xz] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [SaRCGuyyTBOxTjNtvjui-g][es-data-1][/data/data/nodes/0] free: 9.1gb[2%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
```

Following this I freed up resources on that node and now it has enough space available (almost 50%). But logstash is still not able to push data to elastic search and is logging the same error above.

I have the following questions

1. Will elasticsearch recover from this automatically?
2. If not, should I restart the cluster? Is it enough if I just restart the data nodes, or should I be restarting the master and the indest nodes as well?
3. Is there any way to mark the indices writable again without restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually reset the read-only block on your indices.

You can see documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html) in the `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage` block

> The index block must be released manually once there is enough disk
>   space available to allow indexing operations to continue.

```
PUT /<your index name>/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

Comment: This is how you set it for ALL indices: `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`